# Angular material form field isn't working

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I am following this https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview
but in my code form fields behaviour isn't changing also label isn't appearing
for example if the appearance is fill it look like as default form

```
 <mat-form-field  appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
       <input placeholder="FirstName<" formControlName="FName">
 </mat-form-field>
```

Screen
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ihkn.png
but even I change the appearance="standard" or appearance="outline" it doesn't change the behaviour
App-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MessageFormComponent } from './message-form/message-form.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatFormFieldModule, MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from  '@angular/common/http';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MessageFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    HttpClientModule

  ],
  providers: [{provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {appearance: 'fill'}}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

can someone tell what needs to be done

Comment: You need to use the `matInput` directive on your `input` element. Try adding that and your inputs should look like they are supposed to. Double check the examples you linked and notice the differences there.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it doesn't help I tried it didn't work then imported the matinputmodule with this I can't even see the form feild on screen

Comment: You need quite a few modules for this to work: `MatFormFieldModule`, `MatInputModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule` (for the `formControlName` directive) and I would also include the `BrowserAnimationsModule` (optional).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu added module.ts, You can see I have imported all modules

Answer (score 0):

You are all good. just missing `matInput` directive on your `<input>`

```
 <mat-form-field  appearance="fill">
       <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
       <input placeholder="FirstName" matInput> formControlName="FName">
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hi @KLTR, Thanks for your answer but it didn't help, I tried but the didn't find any change